# How does a Swing client communicate with a Java EE backend?

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee

I want to develop a Swing client application that will use a Java EE 6 backend. How does the Swing client communicate with the server? Do I have to make a web service that the communication go through or are there other ways?

Comment: Sockets! It could be RMI, SOAP, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are other ways also in addition to web services.

One very common approach is [RMI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html) or Remote Method Invocation. It is a native extension of the Java platform that allows server-side objects to be directly accessible inside client-side code.

[image: RMI overview]

If you have no experience with RMI then take a look at the official [Java Remote Method Invocation Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaay.html) might be a very useful document for you, complete with diagrams to demonstrate the architecture and communication modal.

Answer (score 1):

There are to many communication types:

- sockets gives to you the max communication speed.
- a little communication overhead, you can use XML / SOAP
- (plain)webservices too : fastest to implement. a HTTP GET, POST
- RMI: I think is deprecated, but others are using. If you want only with Java backend from Java, you can use it

Comment: J2EE spec does not allow serving sockets directly. And RMI is not deprecated, it is the default way of communicating with EJB3 beans.

Comment: sometimes it is good to break specifications (and database normal formes) to have other advantage

Comment: In this case j2ee container would not allow to break specification.

Comment: it is nothing wrong if somebody respect all "specifications" and goes only is allowed, but some can make a hole to get what they need.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can either create a web service (SOAP or RESTful), but since your client is a java application you can use jndi lookup to call EJB3 beans, it will work through rmi or soap, depending or your configuration. Something like [here](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/GettingStarted5.html).